# laravel Livewire 3 | Components are not loading correctly after wire:navigate

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire, flowbite

I am using livewire 3 in my Laravel application i am building an SPA but after a page switch with wire:navigate some components are not loading corrently for example flowbite components.

`document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => { initFlowbite(); });`

Comment: Can you provide more details? What do you mean by components not loading correctly?

Do you have any console errors in DevTools? Have you tried to check the live cycle with other events from livewire and `console.log` inside to dig deeper? Are the same components working as expected, e.g., when using `livewire:load` vs `livewire:navigated`?

Comment: It looks like the js is not loaded for example at this flowbite charts component (https://flowbite.com/docs/plugins/charts/) the js part is not loaded. No console errors.

Comment: Where do you have this script? Do you know if the event fires? Any console errors?

Comment: The scripts are integrated into the app-layout with vite.

Answer (score 0):

### **Long story short:**

Just use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in your component and reinit flowbite. For example, you can add this code at the end of your livewire_component.blade.php file:

```
@script
<script>
const targetNode = document.getElementById("elementsContainer");
const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  initFlowbite();
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

</script>
@endscript
```

### Long story

The problem lies in the need to initialize the Flowbite components that have just been added to the DOM. I've been searching if there is a 'livewire' way of doing this. For example, it'd be nice you could go something like:

```
@script
<script>
$wire.on('after_component_update', ()=>{initFlowbite()});
</script>
@endscript
```

In your Livewire component php code you *dispatch* the 'after_component_update' event when the data have been updated. Or you could even 'hook' the dispatch code to the [rendered hook](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lifecycle-hooks).

Unfortunatly, the event is listened in the front end *before* DOM changes take effect. So I haven't found any other way to go than mutation observer. Let me know if you have another solution.